# Can't access data on a hard drive

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

The screenshot in the link below really says it all.  I have an old laptop hard drive that I've been using with a USB enclosure as a specific backup for certain files that I want to keep. As the screenshot shows, Windows Explorer says the drive is empty, but under Properties it shows 32.5 GB used... those are my files.  I've tried data recovery software (Recuva and EaseUS Data Recovery), and was only able to recover the contents of one subfolder, roughly 18GB.  I really need to get to the rest of my files.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This looks like you have nonstandard partitioning/formatting and/or some filesystem errors. Try to use deep scan regime for to find lost filesystem entries. *was only able to recover the contents of one subfolder, roughly 18GB.* Does ALL these files are NOT damaged? especially huge files.

Comment: You may also investigate HDD's disk/filesystem structures using any direct access software (like WinHex) for correctness and compare it with the characteristics shown by recovery software. Maybe ever use found values while recovery process in expert mode.

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire a professional data recovery service

Comment: _nonstandard partitioning/formatting_      I am just noticing that the drive is showing to be FAT32, but I'm positive I would have never formatted it that way. it would've most definitely been NTFS. 
 
_ALL these files are NOT damaged?_  The files I was able to recover are all healthy and complete with no damage.

_Sounds like you need to hire a professional data recovery service_ I would think the data SHOULD be fairly easy to recover (if this is the solution) because nothing else has ever been put on the drive since I started using it as an external.

Comment: Just a thought... Does anyone think it would be beneficial to do a Quick Format to NTFS and then run the data recovery software again?